# Draw a shapefile in java

Tags: java, shapefile

I would like to read a shapefile in java and then draw it. Are there anyway to read a shapefile and draw it in java? Do you know any useful and easy framework?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [Geotools](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/quickstart/eclipse.html). You can start with this code.

```
public class Quickstart {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File file = JFileDataStoreChooser.showOpenFile("shp", null);
    if (file == null) {
        return;
    }

    FileDataStore store = FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(file);
    SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = store.getFeatureSource();

    // Create a map content and add our shapefile to it
    MapContent map = new MapContent();
    map.setTitle("Quickstart");

    Style style = SLD.createSimpleStyle(featureSource.getSchema());
    Layer layer = new FeatureLayer(featureSource, style);
    map.addLayer(layer);

    // Display the map
    JMapFrame.showMap(map);
}
}
```

Comment: Taken from: http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/quickstart/eclipse.html#things-to-try